# Spring batch step completing but Job not ending

Tags: spring-batch, quartz

I have a Job that has only one step which contains `JdbcPagingItemReader`,`Custom Processor` and `custom writer` that writes to elasticsearch.

Step configuration is

```
jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
.<Entity, WriteRequest>chunk(10000)
.reader(reader)
.processor(processor)
.writer(elasticSearchWriter)
.faultTolerant()
.skipLimit(3)
.skip(Exception.class)
.build();
```

Job Configuration is

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
.preventRestart()
.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
.listener(listener)
.flow(step)
.end()
.build();
```

This job is triggered by a scheduled Quartz job every few mins.

When running this in an environment, **STEP** completes successfully but job stays in status= `COMPLETED` and exit_status=`UNKNOWN` for a very long time, usually 3 - 5 hours and then completes.

There are no logs produced during this inactive period.

One observation is that `commit_count` in `batch_step_execution` has value almost equal to `read_count` which should be usually dependent on chunk size.
**Also, I could see writer writing products one by one instead of writing whole chunks. **

*When running the job in local machine, it works just fine.

Any idea why this might be happening ?

Tried by reducing chunk size to 1000. Now issue is less frequent but `commit_count` still goes up much higher.

Comment: @mahmoud-ben-hassine Can you please help here ?

Comment: What is the difference between these two environments? What is the code of the listener? What does it do? Please share your code to be able to help you efficiently.